# writing to serial port with a shell script

Tags: shell, serial-port

I need to communicate with a serial device by sending it ascii characters. I know that in Linux you can use fopen() to write to a serial port, but I didn't know if you could do that from a shell. If not, is there another simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can simply redirect/cat data to the serial port from the shell.  You'll want to use setserial(8) to configure baud and other information first.